# How to convert the PHAsset type to URL in didfinish method of OpalImagePicker in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am retrieving the videos from albums in PHAsset format using OpalImagePicker() and trying to convert into URL format but it is not working properly and getting into else loop.

```
@IBAction func gallery(_ sender: Any) {

    let imagePicker = OpalImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.imagePickerDelegate = self
    imagePicker.allowedMediaTypes = Set([PHAssetMediaType.video])
    imagePicker.maximumSelectionsAllowed = 4
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePicker(_ picker: OpalImagePickerController, didFinishPickingAssets assets: [PHAsset]) {
    print("entered into multiple video picking")
    presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    for i in 0..<assets.count {
        phassetsarray.append(assets[i])
            print("phassetsarray.count",phassetsarray.count,i)
            let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            options.version = .original
            PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: phassetsarray[i], options: options, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
                if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let localVideoUrl = urlAsset.url

                }else{
                    print("2419")
                }
            })

    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in chat, you are not getting video URLs for some video so you can debug and check error in the issue of OpalImagePickerController. I don't know more about OpalImagePickerController.

You can try this,

```
func imagePicker(_ picker: OpalImagePickerController, didFinishPickingAssets assets: [PHAsset]) {

        print("entered into multiple video picking")

        for asset in assets {

            let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            options.version = .original
            PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: options, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
                if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let localVideoUrl = urlAsset.url
                    print("Video url: \(localVideoUrl.absoluteString)")

                }else{
                    print("2419")
                }
            })

        }

        presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Still, it enters into else loop. Also, I have also added some code regarding selecting videos using OpalImagePicker and I have added the screenshot of my logs.

Comment: but when I run my code it doesn't go to else part and I'm getting video URLs also

Comment: Have you seen at the code which is in the button action? Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, but it is not working. Three days back it worked properly but all of a sudden it is not working. I am flabbergasted.

Comment: Try to clean and build project and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207564/discussion-between-sravya-gajavalli-and-kishan-bhatiya).

Comment: @Lakshmi you have to change in a library for customization. Also, can you ask a separate question for this with detailed information about your question?